# Refresh Listview after guest was created in different form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a Listview that I populate with a List that contains all the guests from the database

```
    private void PopulateListBox()
    {
        var guests = Repository.GetAllGuests();

        foreach (var guest in guests)
        {
            ListViewItem lvData = new ListViewItem(guest.AccountID.ToString());

            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.Username);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.Email);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.FirstName);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.LastName);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.TelephoneNumber);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.AddressLine1);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.AddressLine2);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.City);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.State);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.Postcode);
            lvData.SubItems.Add(guest.Country);

            listViewGuests.Items.Add(lvData);
        }
    }
```

I also have a button with Add Guest:

```
private void btnAddGuest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormAddGuest formAddGuest = new FormAddGuest();
    formAddGuest.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
    formAddGuest.Show();
}
```

this opens up another form where I can add a guest to the database, What I would like to achieve is when a guest was added, it should excecute these two lines:

```
listViewGuests.Items.Clear();
PopulateListBox();
```

In order to refresh the listview, the problem is that I cannot seem to get that working.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ShowDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  , in order to solve this problem

```
private void btnAddGuest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FormAddGuest formAddGuest = new FormAddGuest();
  //formAddGuest.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
  formAddGuest.ShowDialog();
  listViewGuests.Items.Clear();
  PopulateListBox();    
}
```

`FormAddGuest` as soon as you close this form (whether you added guest or not) your list will get rebind.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the MdiParent to the Form that the Add Guest button is in:

```
formAddGuest.MdiParent = this;
```

Then you can access the list from the Add Guest form:

```
((ListView)this.MdiParent.Controls["listViewGuests"]).Items.Clear();
```

And make the PopulateListBox() public so that you can call:

```
this.MdiParent.PopulateListBox();
```